# Windows 7 (particularly office) complains that my temporary directory is missing on hard boot but not after a reboot

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

Whenever I boot my laptop for the first time after a "Shut Down" it tells me it can't open the temporary directory. I then reboot the machine and it's perfectly normal.

Though hardly life threatening it's a very annoying problem, particularly since I can't think of a single difference that windows would know about when comparing turning the computer off & on and "rebooting" it.

Any tips, tricks, pointers, hints, suggestions or cryptic clues appreciated!

Comment: run a "chkdsk /f" on  the hard drive

Comment: That doesn't appear to have helped. No errors were found and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing windows7 service pack 1 appears to have worked.